# show playlist menu in youtube embed

Tags: javascript, youtube-iframe-api

In the top left corner of a youtube playlist embed there is a button to open the playlist menu. I'm trying to have this list opened programatically in the page load. Is there a way to accomplish that?

I think this can be accomplished with `contentWindow.postMessage` but I have no idea what function to use. I could not find any documentation.

Playlist embed code:

https://www.youtube.com/embed/NU1rsLIdpNA?list=PLdIivvLumeIVQHwOsZLYqp3-LZ75X1WKO

Comment: if you're referring to the playlist button in the top right corner, have you tried document.getElementsByClassName('ytp-playlist-menu-button ytp-button')[0].click() ?