# Automatically Open Playlist Menu

Tags: javascript, youtube-data-api

Would have expected this to be an easy task. It's already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104339/show-playlist-menu-in-youtube-embed) without an answer.

I have a basic iframe embedded YouTube Playlist:

```
<iframe 
width="438" 
height="250"         
src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?listType=playlist&list=PL98379246AE853853&index&index=0"
frameborder="0" 
allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; 
gyroscope; picture-in-picture"allowfullscreen="1" 
id="iframe_yt" ></iframe>
```

I want the playlist menu to be open, or to open as soon as the frame is loaded:

[image: YouTube embed with playlist menu open]

This could be built from scratch using the API [along these lines](https://codepen.io/skyrocker/pen/jONrvwO?editors=1011).

I am wondering if there is another way, perhaps by using javascript to `click()` the menu once the frame has loaded.

Possible checking for availability of the

`_yt_player` element something like this:

```
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    console.log(_yt_player);
});
```

My initially chicken scratches are [here](https://codepen.io/MikeiLL/pen/mdbwygO?editors=1010).

Thanks for your input.